# Sum of two ideals is Finitely generated

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, finitely-generated

Suppose $I$ and $J$ are finitely generated ideals in comm ring $R$ then $I+J$ is finitely generated.

Question is converse for this.

- Suppose $I+J$ is finitely generated then $I$ and $J$ are finitely generated?
- Suppose $I+J$ is finitely generated and $I$ is finitely generated then $J$ is finitely generated?
- Suppose $I+J$ is finitely generated and $I$ is nilpotent  finitely generated then $J$ is finitely generated?

I tried proving, failed. Tried to give some counterexamples, failed.

I am sure at least third point is true.

Suggest some hints. Any remarks regarding this if not hints are most welcome.

Comment: For $1$ note that $I+J$ contains $I$ and $J$.For $2$:  $J=I+J+(-I)$.

Comment: @VictorBarg : So, what is your conclusion?

Comment: Does not this show that $1$ and $2$ are true?

Comment: @VictorBarg no, it doesn't. Consider a ring $R$ with some non-finitely generated ideal $J$. Then $R + J = R$ is finitely generated, but $J$ is not. This shows that 1 and 2 are false. In fact, $J$ is not equal to $I + J + (-I)$, as obviously  $-I = I$

Comment: @xyzzyz:I see thank you.

Comment: @xyzzyz : Oh no... :D